# Creating dummy variables in tidyverse syntax?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
dat <- tribble(
  ~isHot, ~isCrispy, ~Restaurant,
  1, 0, "A",
  0, 0, "B",
  1, 1, "B",
  0, 0, "C"
)

> dat
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  isHot isCrispy Restaurant
  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>     
1     1        0 A         
2     0        0 B         
3     1        1 B         
4     0        0 C
```

I want to create dummy variables for all categorical variables to get the following output:

```
  isHot isCrispy Restaurant_A Restuarant_B     
1     1        0 1            0
2     0        0 0            1
3     1        1 0            1
4     0        0 0            0
```

Can I do this just via tidyverse syntax? I don't want to use `recipes`, `fastdummies`, or other packages.

EDIT:

I want the code to be adapted to all categorical variables. In this example there is only one categorical variable, but what if there are more?
I want to be able to take the feature name and create dummies.
For example if there is another categorical feature called City, I would have dummies variables like..City_A, City_B, etc.

Comment: Why do you want that? If you want to perform a regression then you don't need to construct the model matrix explicitly. in the first place.  `lm(y ~ ., dat)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

## tidyr - all categorical columns

To obtain dummy variables for all categorical columns using a 'tidy' approach, we can use **pivot_longer** prior to **pivot_wider**.

```
dat <- tribble(
 ~id, ~isHot, ~isCrispy, ~Restaurant, ~City,
 1, 1, 0, "A", "B",
 2, 0, 0, "B", "B",
 3, 1, 1, "B", "A",
 4, 0, 0, "C", 'A'
)

> dat
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id isHot isCrispy Restaurant City 
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>
# 1     1     1        0 A          B    
# 2     2     0        0 B          B    
# 3     3     1        1 B          A    
# 4     4     0        0 C          A  

dat %>%
 pivot_longer(cols = where(is.character),
              names_to = "dummy_names",
              values_to = "dummy_levels") %>%
 mutate(dummy_value = 1) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = c(dummy_names, dummy_levels),
             values_from = dummy_value, 
             values_fill = 0)
# # A tibble: 4 x 8
#      id isHot isCrispy Restaurant_A City_B Restaurant_B City_A Restaurant_C
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1     1        0            1      1            0      0            0
# 2     2     0        0            0      1            1      0            0
# 3     3     1        1            0      0            1      1            0
# 4     4     0        0            0      0            0      1            1
```

Note the column positions and how they match up with the order of the original data. It shouldn't be too difficult to reorder the columns to your own liking. For example, something like this:

```
dat %>%
 pivot_longer(cols = where(is.character),
              names_to = "dummy_names",
              values_to = "dummy_levels") %>%
 mutate(dummy_value = 1) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = c(dummy_names, dummy_levels),
             values_from = dummy_value, 
             values_fill = 0) %>%
 select(id, isCrispy, isHot, order(colnames(.)))
# # A tibble: 4 x 8
#      id isCrispy isHot City_A City_B Restaurant_A Restaurant_B Restaurant_C
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1        0     1      0      1            1            0            0
# 2     2        0     0      0      1            0            1            0
# 3     3        1     1      1      0            0            1            0
# 4     4        0     0      1      0            0            0            1
```

Answer (score 1):

### dplyr

As requested,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
dat %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number(), val = 1L) %>%
  pivot_wider(c("rn", "isHot", "isCrispy"),
    names_from = "Restaurant", values_from = "val",
    names_prefix = "Restaurant_", values_fill = 0L) %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   isHot isCrispy Restaurant_A Restaurant_B Restaurant_C
#   <dbl>    <dbl>        <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1     1        0            1            0            0
# 2     0        0            0            1            0
# 3     1        1            0            1            0
# 4     0        0            0            0            1
```

but this seems more complex than it needs to be ...

### Base R

```r
model.matrix(~ 0 + Restaurant, data = dat)
#   RestaurantA RestaurantB RestaurantC
# 1           1           0           0
# 2           0           1           0
# 3           0           1           0
# 4           0           0           1
# attr(,"assign")
# [1] 1 1 1
# attr(,"contrasts")
# attr(,"contrasts")$Restaurant
# [1] "contr.treatment"
```

which leads to dplyr-ification as

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(as.data.frame(model.matrix(~ 0 + Restaurant, data = cur_data()))) %>%
  select(-Restaurant)
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   isHot isCrispy RestaurantA RestaurantB RestaurantC
#   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1        0           1           0           0
# 2     0        0           0           1           0
# 3     1        1           0           1           0
# 4     0        0           0           0           1
```

---

**Edit** for your "dynamic factors" request. Since you did not update your sample data, I'll add a column:

```r
dat$QUUX <- c("x","x","y","y")

isfac <- sapply(dat, inherits, c("character", "factor"))
isfac
#      isHot   isCrispy Restaurant       QUUX 
#      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE       TRUE 

out <- do.call(cbind, c(list(dat), lapply(paste("~ 0 +", names(isfac)[isfac]), function(frm) model.matrix(formula(frm), data = dat))))
out[, !names(out) %in% names(isfac)[isfac]]
#   isHot isCrispy RestaurantA RestaurantB RestaurantC QUUXx QUUXy
# 1     1        0           1           0           0     1     0
# 2     0        0           0           1           0     1     0
# 3     1        1           0           1           0     0     1
# 4     0        0           0           0           1     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution I just updated my question. I want it to be dynamic for all categorical variables.

Comment: This is great. Do you have a solution through dplyr?

Comment: Not off-hand, is there a reason this solution can't be used? Not everything needs to be "tidy" to be useful and sufficient :-)

Comment: I was just wondering the solution is good. Need to figure out how to remove 1 of the columns for features with more than 2 unique values. Since one will be a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with `dpylr`

```
dat %>%
  mutate(k = paste0("Restaurant_", Restaurant), v = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = k, values_from = v, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-Restaurant)
```

Comment: Actually you're also using `tidyr` (from `pivot_wider`).

Comment: How can I do this for all categorical variables though? In my example there is only one categorical variable, but how can i adapt the code to work for all dynamically?